# Which is correct, "to have a tendency to <do something>" or "to have the tendency to <do something>"?

Tags: articles

Is the correct phrasing "to have a tendency to <do something>" or is it "to have the tendency to <do something>" ?

An example of a sentence I want to use the phrase in is:
You have a/the tendency to underestimate the effect that future events have on your opinions.

[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20a%20tendency%2C%20have%20the%20tendency&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20tendency%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20the%20tendency%3B%2Cc0#) suggests that the answer is "to have a tendency to <do something>". But I think that the answer might depend on the context.

Comment: Why complicate things? Instead of worrying about whether people *have **a/the** tendency to do something*, just say ***they tend to do it***. But I can't think of any particular reason to use the ***definite*** article in such contexts unless said tendency is already known to the audience (as a tendency which occurs in *other* people, and/or at other times in history, for example).

Comment: It's really confusing  we usually say "to have a tendency to do something", but when talk about ability, we say "to have the ability to do something".

Comment: As written, I would use "a" because people have many tendencies; you are writing about only one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, "a tendency" is the most natural. But, if you think the tendency you describe is a special phenomenon that you want to imply the listener might already be aware of, using "the" might convey that. Or they might just think you're being a tad unidiomatic. Really, though, it doesn't sound that bad even if they don't pick up the nuance you're aiming for.